# How to calculate upload speed with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

After my research about calculating upload speeds. I found out that they are depending on two things:

1. Client internet connection
2. Server internet connection

My application will most likely deal with big uploads of files or even folders. And as I am using Socket.io to handle these resumable uploads, I guess, there will be a 3rd factor - my servers CPU utilization.
*EDIT: The metrics should all happen client-side. The server doesn't need o know about cliens upload speed.*
To measure the upload speed I came along with 2 attempts:

1. Every function call, which sends `x` bytes to the server, get the time `t` and save `x` and `t` for later use.
   On second run and further calculate the upload speed `v` with:
   `v = dx / dt = (x2 - x1) / (t2 - t1)`
2. Every `i` function call, which sends `x` bytes to the server, save `xi` for later use.
   On first call, save the time `t0` and set an async interval function to increment an index `j` and calculate the upload speed every `tj` seconds like this:
   `v = sum(xi) / dt = sum(xi) / sum(tj - t0)`

Theoratically both attempts should give the same output.

But which one is better for the sake of software design and/or performance?

Note:
It makes sense for me to set a strict interval, like in attempt 2. Especially for graphical displaying the calculated information depending on the time while the upload is running. (As in the steam library for instance)

Comment: Do you have a requirement for speed, because all users care about is progress %

Comment: No. There is no requirement for speed.
The progress will also be shown.

Comment: Do you get the total bytes at the start of the upload?

Comment: Yes, I get all information about the data. E.g. data type, size, name...

Comment: Ok if you want metrics on speed, I would go with your first approach and label that metric the function name. So you can say over n runs, what is the speed, or group by client ip address, bc speeds will vary by ip. You can spot check your server connection with speedtest.io. You can tweak your function for performance, tweak your Internet connection, and get a sense of how fast clients are in general.

Comment: I don't see, why the server should know about the clients upload speed.
This all happens client-side, to give the user features, like graphs and ETA.

Comment: Oh. Nevermind then. Your #2 is needed in that case. Sorry to waste your time

Comment: All fine, mate. Thanks for your time. I edited the question.